# Azure Logic App condition to check empty array

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, azure-logic-apps

I am working on a Azure Logic App that returns an empty array after using Filter function. In the next step, I would like to use a condition that can check if the previous array is empty or not. If the output is empty, Then it will return  true and I will do something. So, what is the correct way to write the condition to check if the array is empty ?

[Logic app designer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGDc7.jpg)

Filter Array Step in advance mode: `@startsWith(item()?['LastModified'], utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd'))`

And it returns: []

How to write condition in the next step to check if the body or return value is equal to `[]`. Specially I am not being able to catch this empty array :(

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

You can refer to my `Azure logic app`:

[image]

We need to use the [length expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#length):

```
length(body('Filter_array'))
```

The result seems to be no problem:

[image]